# Why is IIS 10 suddenly returning 302 redirects to the same page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-redirect, iis-10, windows-server-2016

I've had a custom ASP.Net/MVC/C# app working for months as a non-SSL internal-only app on IIS 10 and Windows Service 2016. Now suddenly today one single page of the app is throwing a 302 redirect, and the redirect Location in the header is the same page. All other pages still work fine. No code changes have been made in weeks.

In particular a button click sends it to this Controller url:
http://ppsweb/FSM/SiteDuty/ShowShiftGroupDuties

and the 302 redirect Location in the header looks like this:
Location: /FSM/?r=%2FFSM%2FSiteDuty%2FShowShiftGroupDuties&q=

which ends up returning the user to the Login page.

I have no redirect rules defined in IIS, and the web config contents haven't changed recently. I'm wondering if some under the covers OS upgrade has changed something?

Each time this happens for this one page load I also see an error in the Event Viewer, Application Log, indicating a fault in the CLR.dll:

Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899b8a
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.3946.0, time stamp: 0x6246bcb6
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x000000000002a0a4
Faulting process id: 0x5f0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8ae0ee4e94c58
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 8224bc67-f350-4361-8e21-faafd88a4594
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Please confirm if the session has expired?

Comment: `0xc00000fd` is the famous stack overflow issue (usually caused by bad code). So without analyzing your source code around the problematic URLs, no one can really give an answer.

Comment: Session has not expired, I can repro this 100% of the time when I login and immediately go to the offending page.
And the code was working  fine right up to the point it wasn't, with no changes in even the data the page tries to load.
Not sure even if it was a stack overflow why it would trigger a 302 redirect to itself though?

Comment: Aaarg, Lex Li you were correct! The data being loaded HAD in fact changed (never trust a user's report), and WAS in fact causing stack overflow due to bad code that got stuck in an infinite loop. 
I'm still very puzzled as to why/how that sort of thing would result in a 302 redirect though? 
But thanks for the tip!